# Why is my application marking a binary as quarantined?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

My (sandboxed) OSX application is trying to launch `biber` (a bibliography tool for LaTeX).  However it fails to launch and I get the following message saying that the application has marked biber as quarantined in Console.App.

```
25/03/2013 16:44:15.000 kernel[0]: exec of /private/var/folders/s1/70f5my9n6wq0_kk7bcxjslhh0000gn/T/com.abc.XYZ/par-64756e63616e737465656c65/cache-ef42c8d5d44e40bdd24828b0ae70de275e379c88/biber denied since it was quarantined by XYZ and not approved by Gatekeeper, qtn-flags was 0x00000002
```

This does not happen with any of the other binaries invoked by the application.

This application has an active SSB for the whole harddrive so there are no issues launching, or accessing, external files.

Why and how am I marking that file as quarantined, and how to I remove the quarantine so that it can execute? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** If it helps, the contents of that directory are

- `biber`
- `libperl.dylib`

running ls -l@eOd shows them both to have the attribute com.apple.quarantine, however I'm not sure what copied them into that directory, or how they gained that flag.  The original copies are not quarantined.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this 'biber' is not an application download from Mac App Store or identified developers (with Apple Developer ID). So you must manually allow its launch.
Usually there are three ways to do this:

- Right click on application and click "Open" from the context menu. There will be a warning, just click "Open". OSX will remember your choice and next time it will open.
- You can change Gatekeeper's settings: "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "General" tab. Unlock to make changes. Choose "Anywhere" in the "Allow applications downloaded from" section. **Note**: it decreases security and there will be a warning about it with the proposal to use first solution.
- Remove 'quarantine attribute' from the app. In terminal run command: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <your_app>`

I prefer the last solution. All solutions are for the applications, but I think will also work for the utility.